# Why doesn't the C++ Standard Template Library include a "sort" member function for vectors?

Tags: c++, algorithm, list, vector, stl

I noticed that the C++ Standard Template Library contains a sort member function for list objects, but for some reason it does not contain this member function for vectors.

This just seems sloppy and inconsistent...

**Here is a sample to demonstrate:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

// Template function to print the contents of a container
template <typename Container>
void PrintContainer(const Container& container)
{
    cout << "{ ";
    Container::const_iterator i;
    for (i = container.begin(); i != container.end(); i++)
    {
        cout << *i << ' ';
    }
    cout << "}" << endl;
}

// Main
int main()
{
    vector<int> v;
    list<int> l;

    // Initialize the vector and the list in descending order
    for (int i = 10; i > 0; i--)
    {
        v.push_back(i);
        l.push_back(i);
    }

    // Print the contents
    cout << "Vector = ";
    PrintContainer(v);
    cout << "List   = ";
    PrintContainer(l);
    cout << endl;

    // Sort the vector and the list...
    cout << "Sorting..." << endl << endl;

    // Doesn't work... no member function exists, but why??
    // v.sort();

    // I have to do this annoying garbage instead...
    sort(v.begin(), v.end());

    // Works fine
    l.sort();

    // Print the contents
    cout << "Vector = ";
    PrintContainer(v);
    cout << "List   = ";
    PrintContainer(l);
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I read somewhere that sort and other member functions were added to the list template to ensure that the pointers remained valid after performing different operations, but that doesn't explain why they would choose not to implement this for vectors as well.

***Why would they choose to implement this for lists, but not for vectors?***

Not only would the implementation have been simple, but it would have also made the Standard Template classes more consistent... And consistency is ***VERY*** important when developing an interface that will be learned by millions of programmers and be very widely used!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Not only would the implementation have been simple, but it would have also made the Standard Template classes more consistent...

No, it would not.

Read about the design and philosophy that underpins the STL before making claims about what would be more consistent. It might be more consistent with your expectations, or with other class libraries you've used, but it would not be consistent with the rest of the STL design.

Stepanov's genius, and one of the tenets of [Generic Programming](http://www.generic-programming.org/), was in [lifting](http://www.generic-programming.org/about/glossary.php?term=lifting) common abstractions, separating algorithms from containers, so that the `std::sort()` function works just as efficiently for any random-access container, without needing to be re-implemented again and again on every container.

The rule for the STL is to only define an operation as a member function when it does something that *can't* be done by the general-purpose non-member version. So `list::sort()` allows sorting a list of non-swappable objects, whereas `std::sort()` can't work on a list (because it doesn't have random-access iterators) and requires the elements to be swappable. `list::sort()` is also stable, and preserves iterator validity, see note [6](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/List.html#6) in the STL documentation for `list`:

> The sort algorithm works only for random access iterators. In principle, however, it would be possible to write a sort algorithm that also accepted bidirectional iterators. Even if there were such a version of sort, it would still be useful for list to have a sort member function. That is, sort is provided as a member function not only for the sake of efficiency, but also because of the property that it preserves the values that list iterators point to.

For further discussion of the principle of defining member functions on containers only when they behave differently to the generic algorithm see [Effective STL Item 44](http://ptgmedia.pearsoncmg.com/images/0201749629/items/item44-2.pdf).

Comment: How would it not be simple? it would be as simple as making the member function just call `std::sort`.  I don't see how it could be more simple than that.

Comment: @tjwrona1992: We would need `vector.sort()`, `vector.sort(predicate)`, `vector.sort(iter, iter)` to sort a subrange, `vector.sort(iter, iter, predicate)`. And we would still have `std::sort`. How is this simpler?

Comment: Because that only needs to be added once.  The only way you would have to add another member function is if a new overload for `std::sort` is developed.  It's not very much overhead for a sleek and user-friendly design.

Comment: @tjwrona1992: I think adding __hundreds__ of member functions is crazy talk, would not simplify anything, and would make Alexander Stepanov very sad :)

Comment: @tjwrona1992 Why stop at sort? Why not include find, min_element, partition and all the other algorithms?

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe: He did suggest that in a comment above. Someone please take his computer away.

Comment: @Blastfurnace This is more of a comedy bit than a question.

Comment: @Blastfurnace... Okay you do have a point, but at the very least there should be an implementation of `sort` that can be used on vectors without having to type out "begin" and "end"... why can't you just pass it the whole vector like `sort(v)`?

Comment: @tjwrona1992 if you want, you can write your own function that does that using SFINAE. It would look something like [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/435a3c3f446fe612) though *properly* allowing the name lookup to examine both the `std` namespace and the namespace of the container for the begin and end iterators would take a bit more work.

Comment: @tjwrona1992, `sort(v)` is coming, see [the forthcoming Ranges TS](https://github.com/ericniebler/stl2). The reason it wasn't done originally is that `sort(begin, end)` is the general case, as it can sort sub-ranges not only whole containers. But Eric Niebler and others are working hard to provide the next generation of the STL, that builds on the original. It still won't add member functions to do what can be done better by non-members, because making something look more object-oriented doesn't make it a cleaner, more elegant or more consistent design. It makes it smell of OOP.

Comment: @JonathanWakely, are they going to try and make the general cases work efficiently for lists/maps and other things that have their own member function versions? If the need for these special case member functions could be eliminated that would be even better than making it smell of OOP.

Comment: @tjwrona1992, implementors will be free to overload the non-member function to work faster if that's possible. e.g. in libstdc++ we overload `std::distance()` so that if you give it `begin` and `end` of a `std::list` we don't bother counting the distance, we find the object the iterators belong to and get the distance from it

Answer (score 8):

Actually the real question is "why does `std::list` have a `sort` member when there's a perfectly good `std::sort` algorithm?". (Note: `std::sort` is how you sort `vector` and most other containers)

When you look at the question that way it becomes clear that `list` is the exception to the rule, implementing its own member sort function because for list specifically it can be implemented more efficiently.

This is exactly analogous to `std::find` and `std::map::find` where `map` provides its own find function that works much more efficiently.

Comment: It isn't just a matter of being more efficient. `std::sort` can't be used on lists because it requires random-access iterators, so a separate function is required.

Comment: As Jonathan Wakely pointed out in a comment on the main question, it's also to preserve iterators to elements inside the list (though I don't yet see why this should be a big deal...)

Comment: The situation with list<>::sort is not quite equivalent to map<>::find. std::sort cannot be used for std::list because it requires random iterators.

Comment: @Eugene: that's also a decision though--it's entirely possible to write a quick sort with only bidirectional iterators, for example (or even only forward iterators, if you really want to).

Comment: The thing is realistically the programmer shouldn't have to know this information... They shouldn't need to know the underlying details of sort and why list can be optimized.  If all of the STL constructs had member functions for sort the usage would consistently by `container.sort()` and there would be no confusion about which implementation is better.  Member functions that don't require special optimization could internally call `std::sort`, but the user wouldn't need to know this.  It is more prone to user error the way it is designed now.

Comment: The programmer shouldn't have to learn all of these "exceptions" when it can be implemented in a way that wouldn't require them to learn the exceptions.

Comment: @tjwrona1992 the rule for sorting a container is: if the container has random access iterators, apply the `std::sort` from <algorithm>. Otherwise, find an alternative method. In the case of an `std::list`, [a quick wiki search](http://en.cppreference.com/mwiki/index.php?title=Special:Search&search=list+sort) produces links to the correct function for that special case. Also, you're approaching this entire thing from the perspective of an end-user. Think for a moment about being the person to maintain the mountain of member functions this would ultimately produce--that's not a happy situation.

Comment: @jaggedSpire The member functions would just call `std::sort` (unless they required special functionality like `list`, but that needs to be maintained anyways).  There is no maintenance problem.  The only code to maintain would be in `std::sort`.  If a member function simply calls `std::sort`, any changes made to `std::sort` would effect the member function.

Comment: @tjwrona1992: I can only assume we would then get questions why there is a member function _and_ `std::sort` (you know it's not going away), which one is "better", and why the confusing inconsistency...

Comment: @tjwrona1992 Even simple dispatches to other functions would incur a maintenance burden on the maintainer. Furthermore, when implementing your own container do you want to remember to implement every *single* manipulator function a user might want, only to later add more because someone wanted to be able to reverse every other element, or do you want to provide a small set of accessors, whose abilities can be examined to provide the best method for whatever the user wants? The second allows other libraries to update the functionality of your container as long as it doesn't break encapsulation.

Comment: @Blastfurnace there would not be a question about why both exist.  If there was a member function then the member function would be used.  `std::sort` would still exist as part of the inner workings of the member function.  That would be why `std::sort` would still exist.

Comment: @tjwrona1992 (you just pinged the wrong person--it was Blastfurnace that explained that) The external templated function which accesses a defined set of member functions for its instantiating class is one of the methods used to extend class functionality in C++. In other languages, what you're asking to do is actually a reasonable proposition with only one or two locations to maintain--I believe C# for example allows you to extend class functionality through interfaces, and call the results as member functions.

Answer (score 1):

std::sort and std::stable_sort work with objects like arrays, vectors, anything with random access iterators. std::sort is usually a hybrid quicksort / heapsort, called introsort. std::stable_sort is usually some type of merge sort. std::list:sort is designed to work with singly linked lists. For double linked lists, the internal previous node pointers are taken care of post sort.

std::list::sort algorithm is optimized to work with linked list. Example code that is similar to what is used in HP / Microsoft version of std::list::sort. An array of pointers to the first nodes of internal lists is used, where array[i] is either NULL or points to a list with pow(2,i) nodes (except last pointer list size is unlimited). The actual sort is done using a standard merge lists function. Nodes are taken one at a time and merged into the array, then the array is merged into a single list. This is significantly different than the algorithms used for std::sort or std::stable_sort.

```
NODE * MergeLists(NODE *pSrc1, NODE *pSrc2)
{
NODE *pDst = NULL;                      /* destination head ptr */
NODE **ppDst = &pDst;                   /* ptr to head or prev->next */
    if(pSrc1 == NULL)
        return pSrc2;
    if(pSrc2 == NULL)
        return pSrc1;
    while(1){
        if(pSrc2->data < pSrc1->data){  /* if src2 < src1 */
            *ppDst = pSrc2;
            pSrc2 = *(ppDst = &(pSrc2->next));
            if(pSrc2 == NULL){
                *ppDst = pSrc1;
                break;
            }
        } else {                        /* src1 <= src2 */
            *ppDst = pSrc1;
            pSrc1 = *(ppDst = &(pSrc1->next));
            if(pSrc1 == NULL){
                *ppDst = pSrc2;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return pDst;
}

#define NUMLISTS 32                     /* size of aList[] */
NODE * SortList(NODE *pList)
{
NODE * aList[NUMLISTS];                 /* array of lists */
NODE * pNode;
NODE * pNext;
int i;
    if(pList == NULL)                   /* check for empty list */
        return NULL;
    for(i = 0; i < NUMLISTS; i++)       /* zero array */
        aList[i] = NULL;
    pNode = pList;                      /* merge nodes into aList[] */
    while(pNode != NULL){
        pNext = pNode->next;
        pNode->next = NULL;
        for(i = 0; (i < NUMLISTS) && (aList[i] != NULL); i++){
            pNode = MergeLists(aList[i], pNode);
            aList[i] = NULL;
        }
        if(i == NUMLISTS)
            i--;
        aList[i] = pNode;
        pNode = pNext;
    }
    pNode = NULL;                       /* merge array into one list */
    for(i = 0; i < NUMLISTS; i++)
        pNode = MergeLists(aList[i], pNode);
    return pNode;
}
```